# "s" as a starting extension not working in Asterisk dial plan

Tags: asterisk

I have

```
  [from-pstn]
  exten => s,1,Playback(demo-thanks)
```

as the first line in the context of a dialplan. It does not work.

However, when it is replaced by this:

```
  [from-pstn]
  exten => _X.,1,Playback(demo-thanks)
```

It works. Is the "s" extension not the start extension?

This is the dialplan on a PRI line. When the caller calls in, the first line in the [from-pstn] context is triggered. The "front-pstn" context is referenced in dahdi.conf. That is not the source of the problem as it would not have worked with the _X. extension.

I am just starting to write Asterisk dialplans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s-extensions is empty extension.

I.e it used when no number

Very likly you have number, so it go as number and match regexp X. in your dialplan.

For more info connect to asterisk console, enable verbose output and see what happens while calling

```
asterisk -r
core set verbose 5
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when no number." What number are you referring to? In any event, your answer was useful. If you can clarify further on this one point, I will accept it.

Comment: not all FXO devices/provider send DID number. Some not know number, some not care about.

Comment: The dialplan extension match the DID for an incoming call? And if the DID is not there, then it matches the s extension. Is that it?   I thought that the dialplan has nothing to do with the DID and only with extensions defined in the dialplan with "s" the start pseudo target extension for all incoming calls.

Comment: Dialplan must match dialling number. There are no way determine what it have match by info you provided. You have read asterisk book for beginner.